# Jira: I have an issue, but it is not counted in the map to columns tool of my board

Tags: jira

I have a project for which I can add and edit issues. When I create a board, I normally map issue types to board columns (e.g. if I have 5 todo issues not in the current board, normally the system lets me map todo(5) to the todo column).

For my current project, all my issue statuses are marked as having (0) issues associated, yet I have a dozen issues which should appear. Please see the attached screenshot.

Cheers,

Albert.[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems the board was somehow corrupted. I just discarded it and created a new board, and now the issues appear as expected.